# namaz question while missing prayer

Tags: salat

question:if we arrive after the first rakath, then should we join the prayer by making neeyat and reciting sana or just join and later after imam makes salmam we should stand up and then recite sana and continue the prayer?

Comment: Also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/how-should-i-perform-the-missed-rakats-if-joined-a-group-prayers-in-the-third-un

Comment: Not duplicate, since the question is particularly about reciting Sana, and if the other thread has answered this, then I have somehow missed it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the info available on Islamic Centre, you do not recite sana when you join late, and instead recite sana on your first make up rakath after the imam has given salaam.

http://www.islamiccentre.org/component/content/article?id=893